# PHP equivalent of openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac KEY -binary

Tags: php, bash, hash, openssl, sign

I try to implement this bash command in PHP without success :

`password='echo -en "$date" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $apiKey -binary | openssl enc -base64'`

I tried the openssl_digest and openssl_encrypt without success.
I don't understand the order of the parameters...

Could you help me to generate the expected command in PHP ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Isn't that basically just `hash_hmac()`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried that :

`$password = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $date, $apiKey, true));`

But that seems not works

Comment: I can' t reproduce this, both results are identical on my machine. Maybe you should post a concrete example with defined input values (date, apiKey) and the results for both bash and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
hash_hmac was the correct method to use, the next concern came from using GuzzleHttp\Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash command :

```
password='echo -en "$date" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $apiKey -binary | openssl enc -base64'
```

can be interpreted in PHP as follows :

```
$password = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $date, $apiKey, true));
```